# Ajax call to API to retrieve JSON data. How do you use the response back

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I am making a simple chrome application that calls my REST API to retrieve some basic user information in the JSON format. I have the below which in chrome developer tab preview shows to be working, connecting and retrieving what ever I put in my request.

My question is how do I go about dynamically showing on my html page what ever is retrieved?

Ideally I what to just show certain fields only from my response. I.e. just the Name, Location, Contact number as variables I can use throughout my page.

Any pointers would be great. Thanks

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Connect to API</title>
  <style>
  img {
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

var authorizationToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
function myapiRequest(endpoint, method, options) {
  $.ajax($.extend({}, {
    type: method,
    dataType: "json",
     success: function(json) {
              items = json;
            },
    url: "https://api.myapi.com/" + endpoint,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Token token=" + authorizationToken,
      "Accept": "application/vnd.myapi+json;version=2"
    }
  },
  options));
}
myapiRequest('/users/0H5G?include%5B%5D=contact_methods&include%5B%5D=teams'); // this will be a variable soon

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Response 200 OK

```
{"user":{"name":"john smith Jsmith","email":"john smith @xxxxxxx.com","time_zone":"Asia/Hong Kong","phone":"0123456",}}
```

Comment: Which content do you want to change, the html you provided is blank.. First decide where you want to put the data in, make a static html page with dummy data. and then change the data of it with the data from your response..

Comment: This is the page I want to put the data in.....I want to call, get my data and show the data all from one place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
  success: function(response) {
   // if your response is in JSON format, you can access response keys 
   // in the following format (both ways give same result) 
    var title = response.title; // OR var title = response['userId']);
    
    // ...and then append to the DOM (your HTML) by selecting the
    // element you want to append to, and using the append method
    $('div.append-to-me').append(title);
    
  },
  error: function(error) {
   console.log('not implemented');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="append-to-me"></div>
```